# Only last iteration of loop is saved

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes (subspec2) which I want to loop through to get the columns with the maximum value from each dataframe, and write these to a new dataframe. I wrote the following loop:

```
good.data<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=401, ncol=78)) #create empty dataframe

for (i in length(subspec2)) ##subspec2 is the list of dataframes

{

max.name<-names(which.max(apply(subspec2[[i]],MARGIN=2,max))) #find column name with max value
good.data[,i]<-subspec2[[i]][max.name] #write the contents of this column into dataframe

}
```

This seems to work but only returns values in the last column, nothing else appears to have been saved. Many threads point out the df must be outside the loop, but that is not the problem here.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to change `for (i in length(subspec2))` to `for (i in 1:length(subspec2))`. The former will only do 1 iteration, where `i = length(subspec2)` whereas the latter iterates over multiple `i`s.

*(I am pretty sure that is your issue, but one thing that is great to do is to create a reproducible example so I can run your code to double check, for example I am not exactly sure what `subspec2` looks like, and I am not able to run your code as it is, a great resource for this is the [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) package).*

Comment: Thanks Lucy! That was exactly my error. Maybe one day I'll stop spending hours on solving these tiny errors! And you're absolutely right I should have provided a reproducible example.